# Find CPU usage of a specific process

Tags: powershell, performance

I'm trying to write a PowerShell program that "records" a process CPU and RAM usage.
After searching for ways to do it I found about the command Get-Counter.

Now it works perfectly fine for RAM but I just can't understand the values I'm getting from the CPU.

For example when I tested my program I check a process that used about 10% CPU(according to Task Manager), but when checking with Get-Counter I get a value around 90.

Now I know Get-Counter takes all the logical processors into account.

But I have 16 logical processors, so I just can't see where the 90 is coming from.

If someone knows either how to make sense of the value I'm getting, or if there is another way to record CPU usage I will be thankful.

Comment: Aside from get-process?

Answer (score 0):

without seeing (at least) part of the code it will be hard to tell why you are getting different value (might be wrong counter, wrong value [raw, second, cooked], or maybe even some calculations being performed within your script). Either way my guess would be that you are querying raw value rather than "cookedvalue"